# MS Access: Query Browser-like Functionality?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there any way to execute an SQL statement, and view the returned result set in MS Access without having to go through any wizards, the query design view, or creating a form? Kind of like the functionality of the MySQL Query Browser. I usually like to test my queries before I embed them into some sort of GUI (when working with MySQL and Oracle previously). Working with Access has been a bit of an annoyance for me: there is a lot dependency on wizards, and even the "design" views has way too much hand-holding.

Comment: In the Access query designer, switch to SQL View --- no wizardly cruft or hand holding to get it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the view in the Query Designer to SQL View.

This will allow you to hand-craft your SQL without the need to use the inbuilt wizards.

Comment: ...but don't get too attached to the details of your "handcrafted" SQL -- the QBE will reformat it to its own internal standards and lose any non-vanilla formatting you put into it. I strongly recommend that 99% of users get used to just using the QBE and never dip into SQL view except for the functions that can't be performaned in the QBE itself.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: IIRC it only see the reformatting when a Query object is saved and reopened. Also, you've exaggerated the effects: for example, (again IIRC) generating a query using the QBE thing will put quoted identifiers (square brackets) a column name (ditto parentheses around individual predicates) that doesn't actually need them, however hand crafting without will not cause them to be added on reopening.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: ...it would be interesting to learn what does get reformatted. The worest one, og course, is when a derived table (subquery in the `FROM` clause) is rewritten using square brackets and breaks when the subquery relies on quoted identifiers (which *require* square brackets), which is really daft, but IIRC doesn't get rewritten in every case. Alsi IIRC (again) some whitespace and linefeeds get added/removed. I keep having to say IIRC because I don't have Access installed!

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: for one who can already write SQL, using the QBE thing to write one's SQL is a huge step backwards! The specific things I dislike include the way it handles subqueries (requires SQL!) and its lack of support for writing constraints.

Comment: The fact is, if you want your SQL to run in Access, the easiest way to accomplish that is to START from the QBE, and then adjust the SQL manually in SQL view when you need to do something the QBE doesn't support. Hours of grief can be avoided by using the QBE for what it's good for, instead of insisted on putting hair on your chest by writing your SQL by hand (and often ending up with SQL that isn't compatible with Access/Jet/ACE).

Comment: I find it most convenient to at least start my queries in the designer.  It allows me to quickly choose data sources, assign aliases, set up joins the way Access wants them, and select fields with less opportunity for speeling errors.  From there, I often switch to SQL View for the kind of stuff where it feels like the query designer "gets in my way".  I could do the whole thing in SQL View, but it would take a little longer.